# Python - how to avoid getting full data from Firebase?

Tags: python, security, firebase-realtime-database, kivy, rules

I'm working on a mobile app and sending the user data (email, pw, inputs) to Firebase Realtime Database. However, I noticed that when I use the following codes in app;

```
request  = requests.get(self.url+'?auth='+self.auth)
data = request.json()
content= list(data)
print (content)
```

I'm able to get the full data even the username is different. In other words, if user "A" is logged in that user should be able to retrieve only its own data, not anyone else's.

Could any one help with this how can I adjust the rules on Firebase to allow users to retrieve only their own data, but the rules should also allow new users be a subscriber? (I tried some existing rules -see below one of them- but this time it did not allow for new user registration).

```
{
     "rules":{ 
       "users":{
        "$user_id":{
          ".read": "auth != null && "$user_id == auth.uid",
          ".write": "auth != null && "$user_id == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my DB structure.

```
{
  "kayitlar" : {
    "-MlPA3fxwjcIkpcJyxQ4" : {
      "userA@gmail-com" : {
        "GS" : "0",
        "KA" : "220",
        "PW" : "xxxyyy",
        "SA" : "SA-220",
        "USR" : "oley",
      }
    },
    "-MlPG3i-A4DFmvJyFzvV" : {
      "userB@gmail-com" : {
        "GS" : "0",
        "KA" : "440",
        "PW" : "cccvvv",
        "SA" : "SA-220",
        "USR" : "oley",
      }
    },
    "-MlPINim6C3nuiA2wIYu" : {
      "userB@gmail-com" : {
        "GS" : "2",
        "KA" : "136",
        "PW" : "cccvvv",
        "SA" : "SA-220",
        "USR" : "oley",
      }
    }
  },
  "musderi" : {
    "userB@gmail-com" : {
      "Password" : "cccvvv",
      "Username" : "oley"
    },
    "userA@gmail-com" : {
      "Password" : "xxxyyy",
      "Username" : "rolex"
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAiFD.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Hi Alex, just added it. Thanks.

Comment: What does `self.auth` return?

Comment: It is database secret of Firebase. Added the screenshot of it.

Comment: Is there anyone can help with this issue?